# Converted sorted array to a height-balanced binary search tree

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm solving [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/) to convert a sorted integer array to a binary search tree. A height-balanced binary tree is a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differs by more than one.

Recursive solution is fairly straightforward, but iterative solution seems to be much more complicated. I came up with the following pretty sub-optimal and not that concise implementation:

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode() {}
    public TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    public TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

private static int[] leftNode(int[] arr){
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length / 2);
}

private static int[] rightNode(int[] arr){
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length / 2 + 1, arr.length);
}

private static int root(int arr[]){
    return arr[arr.length / 2];
}

public static TreeNode sortedArrayToBstIterative(int[] nums){
    if(nums == null || nums.length == 0){
        return null;
    }
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(root(nums));
    List<int[]> parts = Arrays.asList(leftNode(nums), rightNode(nums));
    List<TreeNode> level = Collections.singletonList(root);
    int notVisited = nums.length - 1;
    while(notVisited > 0){
        List<TreeNode> nextLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int[]> nextParts = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<int[]> iterator = parts.iterator();
        for(TreeNode node: level){
            int[] left = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
            if(left != null && left.length != 0){
                TreeNode leftNode = new TreeNode(root(left));
                node.left = leftNode;
                nextLevel.add(leftNode);
                nextParts.add(leftNode(left));
                nextParts.add(rightNode(left));
                notVisited--;
            }
            int[] right = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
            if(right != null && right.length != 0){
                TreeNode rightNode = new TreeNode(root(right));
                node.right = rightNode;
                nextLevel.add(rightNode);
                nextParts.add(leftNode(right));
                nextParts.add(rightNode(right));
                notVisited--;
            }
        }
        parts = nextParts;
        level = nextLevel;
    }
    return root;
}
```

The solution is basically about splitting the given array into 2 subarrays until all of the elements are used.

It works fine, but the question is if there's another more concise solution to produce height-balanced binary search tree?

Comment: Check out [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please note that [posting the exact same question to two or more sites is strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Consider deleting this question if you decide to ask it over there.

Comment: @greybeard Thank you very much for the comment. I believe it better suites to the SO site since I ask about another approach like different algorithm or another implementation technique though

Answer (score 0):

Don't write, never commit or publish undocumented code:
In Java, use [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).
You create a lot of arrays.
Give using `java.util.Arrays.asList()` & `List.subList(from, to)` a try.

As a [complete binary tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#complete) is *balanced enough*, that should be easier to construct.

Comment: In computing, one resource to spare is programmer time.